# React Using Correct Memo for Table Column Mapping

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that uses HandsOnTable to render a table (not necessarily important to the issue but figured I'd give context).

Every time the component renders the table, it runs a renderer function on every column header to handle formatting. I want to memoize the this function pumping out the columns because tables can have 100+ columns and the renderer/formatter it getting very expensive on the big tables.

```
const getSettings = () => {
  // getSettings only runs once or twice, but getTableColumns will run once for every column
  return {
    columns: getTableColumns
  }
}

const getTableColumns = (index) => {
  const column = data[index]

  const renderer = () => {
    // expensive formatting using the column data
  }

  return {
    renderer
  }
}
```

I'm unsure which to use, `memo`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`; I'm new to the memo situation in React. Also, I've read the React versions of memo aren't like actual memo like in lodash? Here is what I've tried:

```
columns: useMemo(() => getHotColumns, [props.selectedNode])
```

This unfortunately throws an error: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Every time the user selects a new node on my graph UI I want to rerender my table to handle the new data, aka when `props.selectedNode` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick version:

It sounds to me like what you actually want here is to memoize the output of each `renderer` invocation. That could looks something like this:

```
// This is the important bit, we are caching the rendered output for each column
const renderedColumns = useMemo(() => {
  const renderer = (columnData) => {
    // expensive formatting using the column data
  }

  return your_column_data.map(renderer);
}, [your_column_data]);

const getTableColumns = (index) => {
  // Return the cached value instead of re-calculating
  return renderedColumns[index];
};

// This memoization sounds like it is less important, but it doesn't hurt.
const columnSettings = useMemo(() => ({
  columns: getTableColumns
}), [getTableColumns]);
```

---

> I'm unsure which to use, `memo`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`

Quick overview, as I understand it:

- `memo` - Memoizes a React component. This means that it won't rerender unless one of its props change. (normally, if the parent rerenders, so will the child)
- `useMemo` computes and caches a value until one of the values in the specified dependencies array changes, in which case it will recalculate using the provided function.
- `useCallback` afaik this is identical to `useMemo`, just has a cleaner interface for memoizing functions.

Comment: Should be noted, I'm doing a bit of guesswork here because I'm not 100% sure what variables you have and what exactly you need to provide to this table lib. Lmk if this seems off.

Comment: Thanks! This is working but my only issue is that `getTablesColumns` is rendering over and over again for X number of columns. `columnSettings` is not rerendering though...

Comment: Actually sorry, I think it's because I added a console.log inside the memo which would cause it to not memo correctly? I'm pretty sure the console.log was causing the issue

Comment: Hmm, having a `console.log` inside the memo func shouldn't affect the way the memo works afaik.

Comment: `getTableColumns` at this point should be a function that is quick (just an object lookup), so I think it should be fine that it gets executed multiple times.